# ViewPager Inside ScrollView is not showing Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am having a strange problem, I have an Activity which has a vertical scrollview. ScrollView has 8 ViewPagers, each ViewPager has fragments. When i scroll down the scrollview to 7th viewpager i see the five pagerIndicator dots but fragments are not visible in that. I see blank viewpager.

But when i put that same viewpager on 1st or 2nd position every thing works fine and Fragments are visible without changing any code.

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter for showing fragments in viewpager. Here is my FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
static class CompanyFactAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<BaseFragment> mFragmentList;

    public CompanyFactAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<BaseFragment> fragment) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentList = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       return mFragmentList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

where mFragmentList contains fragments to show in ViewPager

I have a scroll view only and viewPagers are added at run time. Below is the layout file which i inflate in scrollview at run time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_company_fact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/indicator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

               <com.firstrain.ui.widget.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:fillColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:paddingStart="5dp"
                app:radius="4dp"
                app:strokeColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Activity layout containing scrollView:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<com.firstrain.ui.widget.CustomScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_summery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

        </LinearLayout>

</com.firstrain.ui.widget.CustomScrollView>
```

Comment: show your layout file

Comment: question edited @MarcinOrlowski